# Transaction does not rollback when exception occurs outside controller

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, transactions, playframework-2.0

I'm facing some trouble trying to rollback an transaction when my code throws an exception. If I thrown an exception directly on my controller without handlyng, the transaction will rollback fine but I couldn't make work when I thrown an exception from another class and handle this exception how is shown in the code below.

**This is my controller.**

```
  @Dynamic("EDIT_MANUAL_COMPENSATION")
@Transactional
public static Result save() {
    try {
        JsonNode request = request().body().asJson();
        Long[] financialsId = JSONUtils.fromJson(request.get("financials"), Long[].class);
        ManualReceivementStatus action = JSONUtils.fromJson(request.get("action"), ManualReceivementStatus.class);
        FinancialLaunchClient.markManualFinancialsAs(financialsId, action);//SOME EXCEPTION GENERATED HERE
        return ok();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return createErrorMessage(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the exception thrown by FinancialLaunchClient.markManualFinancialsAs(..) a Runtime or a checked exception?

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, is thrown by FinancialLaunchClient.markManualFinancialsAs(..). I tried both checked and unchecked exception. Got the same result.

Comment: The question I asked which you have not answered is whether the exception thrown by FinancialLaunchClient.markManualFinancialsAs(..) is a checked or unchecked exception.

Comment: Anyway your code is never throwing an exception as you catch it and deal with it. Put the transactional code is a Service class. This throws an exception and the controller handles and deals with the output. The transaction is committed or rolled back when the service method completes.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense to me. The code in FinancialLaunchClient.markManualFinancialsAs(..) is throwing an exception so any modificatons done in this method should be rolled back. By the way, as I said before, I tried checked and unchecked exception

Comment: Sorry but you're mistaken. **As you catch it and do not re-throw it - an exception is never thrown across a transactional boundary** and that is what you are missing. Try it and see....

Comment: Hi, yeh you were right! So, i guess the way to go is catch the exception in my controller and then re-throw it. This way Play will make a rollback. right?